# Chart Js , multiples lineas en un label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**Requerimiento**

- Poder insertar dos lineas en un label, es decir que cuando pulse "AQUI DOS LINEAS " se activen o desactiven las dos lineas que asigne.

**Imagen:**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esperado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://jsfiddle.net/palaceslittle/sehf31cy/

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [
        {
            label: 'AQUI DOS LINEAS',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',    
            borderWidth: 1
        },
            {
            label: 'Xxxx',
            data: [22, 29, 33, 55, 52, 33],
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',    
            borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="1500" height="290"></canvas>
```

Comment: ¿Con qué problemas te estás encontrando? ¿Recibes algún error? Tal y como está redactada la pregunta ahora mismo, no se entiende muy bien qué es lo que quieres o cómo debería funcionar el código.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro hola Alvaro, el requerimiento que mencione arriba se refiere a poder insertar dos lineas en un label, es decir que cuando haga click en el boton "Aqui dos lineas", desaparezcan de a dos.

Comment: Sigo sin comprender qué es lo que quieres que ocurra cuando se pulse en "Aqui dos lineas", ¿a qué te refieres con que desaparezcan de a dos?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Fijate que hay dos lineas trazadas. Lo pedido en el requerimiento es juntar las dos en un solo label, de manera que al hacer click en el boton "aqui dos lineas" aparezcan o desaparezcan las dos.

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres es que si se pulsa en uno de los `label` se borren las dos líneas de la gráfica, ¿correcto? ¿O sólo en el de "Aqui dos lineas"? **Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir toda la información, los comentarios pueden borrarse y perderse (y no se pueden buscar)**

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Exactamente eso, pero que el label Xxxx como llame en la imagen deje de existir. Es decir controlar las dos con un label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En ChartJS puedes definir tus propios `labels` y el comportamiento que van a tener. Lo que tienes que hacer es en las opciones de configuración, para las leyendas (`legend`), definir cuántos `labels` va a haber (en tu caso sólo una con el texto "AQUI DOS LINEAS") y las acciones que van a ocurrir cuando se pulsan (con `onClick`).

Aquí puedes ver cómo sería el código comentado:

```
....
options: {
    ....
    // aquí va la configuración de las leyendas
    legend: {
      // aquí los datos de los labels
      labels: {
        // generamos un único label del color que quieres
        generateLabels: function(chart) {
          return [{
            text: 'AQUI DOS LINEAS',
            fillStyle: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
          }]
        }
      },
      // aquí definimos el comportamiento que ocurrirá cuando se pulse la leyenda
      onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
        var ci = this.chart;
        // para cad una de las líneas de datos
        ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
          var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);
          // si están visibles las escondemos y viceversa
          if (meta.hidden == true) {
            meta.hidden = false;
          } else {
            meta.hidden = true;
          }
        });
        // redibujamos la gráfica
        ci.update();
      }
    }
    ....
  }
....
```

Y aquí te pongo una pequeña demo basada en tu código:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'AQUI DOS LINEAS',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        label: 'Xxxx',
        data: [22, 29, 33, 55, 52, 33],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        hidden: true
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      labels: {
        generateLabels: function(chart) {
          return [{
            text: 'AQUI DOS LINEAS',
            fillStyle: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
          }]
        }
      },
      onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
        var ci = this.chart;
        ci.data.datasets.forEach(function(e, i) {
          var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(i);
          if (meta.hidden == false) {
            meta.hidden = true;
          } else {
            meta.hidden = false;
          }
        })
        ci.update();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="1500" height="290"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfecto! , era lo que buscaba. 
Se puede establecer que el label  inicie desactivado por defecto?

Comment: Le puedes poner `hidden: true` a los dataset para que no se muestren por defecto. He cambiado la demo un poco para que funcione

Comment: Genial, ultima cosa. Puedo agregar otro label que contenga otras dos lineas distintas? . Es decir .. [   ]AQUIDOSLINEAS,   [   ]AQUIOTRASDOS

Comment: Se podrían añadir más labels a las leyendas y cambiar un poco el comportamiento del `onClick`, pero creo que entonces sería demasiado específico, quizás sería mejor otra opción sin generar nuevos labels para hacerlo más genérico

Comment: En que parte agregaría los labels? no logro llegar al resultado